# SQL query for combining data from the same table

Tags: sql

I have this table :

```
create table mytable 
(ID varchar(10), VNDCOD INT, MANUF varchar(10), PRICE INT, COST INT);

insert into mytable values

 ('4', 1000, 'AG', 5455, 9384),
 ('4', 1000, 'A1', 16, 31),
 ('4', 2000, 'AG', 5253, 8339)
```

I want to be able to select something like this:

```
ID   MANUF   PRICE   COST    PRICE   COST
4    AG      5455    9384    5253    8339
4    A1        16      31
```

If there is two `MANUF` for an `ID`, we should combine them on one line where the `PRICE` and `COST` of the one with `VNDCOD 1000` is on the left and `VNDCOD 2000` on the right like in my expected result. I don't know if it is possible to do this in one query. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'd have to use a [dynamic pivot on multiple columns](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns/) to do this, likely using `ROW_NUMBER()`.  Personally, I'd consider this a display issue that should be handled in the application.  Doing this sort of thing is difficult with SQL because it's breaking first normal form.  The language wasn't written with this sort of thing in mind.  You could almost say it's *intentionally* difficult.

Comment: What is the problem with the solutions bellow? It was easier and neater to have only one cursor to loop in my SQLRPGLE program to populate my subfile.

Comment: My assumption was that `VNDCOD` was going to have many different possible values, not represented by two possible values.  Philosophically, though, you're taking two columns and splitting them into four and creating repeating groups.  In a trivial case like this it will all work fine, but it won't scale very far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use a self-join or a MAX(CASE) ([fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/151a5/6):

```
select t1.ID, t1.MANUF, t1.PRICE, t1.COST, t2.PRICE, t2.COST 
from mytable as t1 left join mytable as t2
  on t1.ID = t2.ID
 and t1.MANUF = t2.MANUF
 and t2.VNDCOD = 2000
where t1.VNDCOD = 1000
;

select ID, MANUF, 
   max(case when VNDCOD = 1000 then PRICE end), 
   max(case when VNDCOD = 1000 then COST end), 
   max(case when VNDCOD = 2000 then PRICE end), 
   max(case when VNDCOD = 2000 then COST end)
from mytable 
group by ID, MANUF
```

Answer (score 0):

You can readily do this with conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       max(case when vndcode = 1000 then price end) as price_1000,
       max(case when vndcode = 1000 then cost end) as cost_1000,
       max(case when vndcode = 2000 then price end) as price_2000,
       max(case when vndcode = 2000 then cost end) as cost_2000
from mytable t
group by id;
```